# Getting an error while fetching excel from share point

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to fetch data from share point (excel), but I am getting an error "failure creating file" when I try to pass Share point path

```
 public string Get(int CSIID)
    {
        //string FilePath = @"C:\Dev\TestSheet.xlsx";
        string FilePath = "https://globalfunctionsshare.nam.citi.net/sites/otdrrm/_layouts/15/WopiFrame.aspx?sourcedoc=/sites/otdrrm/Documents/tools/Legal%20Hold%20Application%20Tracker/Legal%20Hold%20Application%20Tracker%2020210702.xlsx";
        DataTable dt = ImportExceltoDatatable(FilePath, CSIID);
        string Status = dt.Rows[0]["Preservation Status"].ToString();
        return Status;
    }
    public DataTable ImportExceltoDatatable(string Filepath, int CSI_ID)
    {
        // string sqlquery= "Select * From [SheetName$] Where YourCondition";
        string sqlquery = "Select [Preservation Status] From [Sheet1$] Where [CSI ID]="+CSI_ID;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        string constring = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + Filepath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;\"";
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constring + "");
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(sqlquery, con);
        da.Fill(ds); //--> Here i'am getting error
        DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
        return dt;
    }
```

I know that the error has something to do with the share point path because this just works fine if I give my local path.

Comment: Are you trying to execute above code on sever or client side?

Comment: See, I have been given this share point path and been told to get the records through API. So i am writing this piece of code on my machine.

Comment: You aren't doing that though. You're trying to open the Excel file for reading instead of getting it. ADO.NET is a data access method, not an HTTP client. If you want to work with OLEDB, you need to download the file first.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: So can I read excel file from excel on share point and retrieve a single value (which I need in my case) without downloading it?

Comment: There are two columns Id and status.. so based on the ID that i'll get through my API call i want the status against it, which i am getting through above code. but if the excel is on my local machine, the moment i use share point path i get an error

Comment: Yes/No/Maybe. Depends on the version, whether it's on premise or SharePoint Online. SharePoint had [Excel Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/excel-services-in-sharepoint) between 2007 and 2016. In 2016 they were removed from the on-premise version. They're still available in Excel Online

Comment: What is your *real* question? You asked about your attempted solution, not the actual problem. You can't just try code at random until it works, especially not with SharePoint. It's not a local disk you can read from. It's Google Docs, and Sheets and Sites and a lot more packaged in a single service. It has its own way of working and API, with its own quirks and way of working.

Comment: Look i first thought of writing a code through which i could read excel file from my local path and if that piece of code works i'll replace the path with share point path. but unfortunately as you said share point is not an easy thing to play with. So now you know my requirement so can you please help me in achieving it. It will be of great help

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Could you help me please?